# Java API to Connect to SAP through Oracle Web Logic and Oracle Enterprise Service Bus

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, sap, osb

We have gotten a requirement for our application to "Your product shall be able to attach data from SAP through Oracle Web Logic and Oracle Enterprise Service Bus.".

The information that should be imported is resources (personnel mostly) and some of their attributes.

According to the customer our product should "be configured by us to connect to the above mentioned services and import the information". To me that seems a bit hard to do because of all the possibilities, data types, constraints and such.

Our app is written in Java and is a desktop application.

The information around SAP/ESB and Web Logic is substantial, to say the least. I have Googled a lot but it's hard to get past all the hight level architecture information. Similar questions here at stackoverflow did not give any help unfortunately.

Is the requirement that the app should be "configurable by the customer" to basically import any information they choose, without our help, even possible?

I would appreciate if anyone with experience could point me in the right direction. Maybe an API to connect to such things. To connect to a general database one would use JDBC or Hibernate. But is there such an API to connect to Oracle ESB, or is that done is a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is going to be hard to answer since it is so broad but here is some info that may be of use. Maybe you can narrow down what you're looking for based on this answer.

The Oracle Service Bus has a SAP Adapter that you can use to do queries that may suit your needs. This tutorial shows how to run a SAP query from within the OSB, which almost sounds like exactly what you need:

https://blogs.oracle.com/ateamsoab2b/entry/using_sap_adapter_ps3_with

Weblogic and the ESB also have their own API that you can use for configuration, including creating new endpoints, importing/exporting projects etc. If you start looking into WLST you may find some of what it does useful for your project. This is a good starting place but there are many more examples/tutorials out there:

http://www.qualogy.com/oracle-service-bus-wlst-fundamentals/

Comment: In the docs for the first link I see install steps that mention database installs and what not. I am looking for a client API that connects to such databases/services.
The second link seems more promising.
I would like to know how the requirements should be interpreted though. And they are in fact not more explicit than that. :(